# stringdist_join not merging data

Tags: r, merge, fuzzy-comparison, fuzzyjoin

I have three data frames that need to be merged. There are a few small differences between the competitor names in each data frame. For instance, one name might not have a space between their middle and last name, while the other data frame correctly displays the persons name (Example: Sarah JaneDoe vs. Sarah Jane Doe). So, I used the fuzzy join package. When I run the below code, it just keeps running. I can't figure out how to fix this.

Can you identify where I went wrong?

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
library(tidyverse)

temp1 = read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bandcar/bjj/main/temp1.csv')

stats=read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bandcar/bjj/main/stats.csv')

winners = read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bandcar/bjj/main/winners.csv')


#perform fuzzy matching full join
star = stringdist_join(temp1, stats, 
                by='Name', #match based on Name
                mode='full', #use full join
                method = "jw", #use jw distance metric
                max_dist=99, 
                distance_col='dist') %>%
  group_by(Name.x)
```

Comment: Your code also runs for quite a while on my machine, but it's probably because `star` has more than 50 million rows when you do a `full` join.

Comment: Did it actually complete the merge? it just keeps running for me. I interrupted it and tried left join, but it was the same story.

Comment: Yes, after a couple of minutes. Try an inner join for starters.